# AND/OR list inside command grouping which ends by asynchronous operator or "{ cmd1 && cmd2; } &"

Tags: posix, sh

I want to execute many commands in parallel in `~/.xinitrc`.

This is easy archived by POSIX sh syntax:

```
cmd & cmd & ...
```

but some of them have dependencies and run in sequence, but each sequence in parallel.

I come with:

```
{ cmd1 && cmd2; } &
cmd3 &
{ cmd4 || cmd5; } &
```

Is `cmd1` and `cmd2` executed in single sh process which forked from original sh?

I understand what say POSIX for each of:

- `&&` - AND list
- `&` - asynchronous list
- `{ ...; }` - compound list for execution in current environment

but don't can deduce execution semantic when those syntax units used together.

Is `(cmd)` equivalent to `{cmd;} &`?

Do `(...)` syntax (subshell) help me to archive my goal?

Comment: I think you may get better help over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct.

```
{ cmd1 && cmd2; } &
```

forks a single new shell, in which `cmd1` runs to completion, followed by `cmd2` if successful.  `(cmd)` starts a new subshell, but waits for that shell to complete before continuing. `{ ...; } &` and `( ... ) &` are similar; I don't recall if the second starts an additional process for each of `(...)` and `&`, or if it can simply run the new process for `(...)` in the background.